# vue2 'computed' value created after 'created' value

Tags: vuejs2

I am confused cause when I search google and find articles all tell me in vue's life cycle, 'computed' was before 'created',but in my code, i got result 2 
before result 1, how can resolve this?

```
computed: {
    options() {
        const imgData = {
          img: this.modifyData,
          fixedNumber: this.ratio
        }
        console.log(1)
        return Object.assign({}, this.defaultOptions, imgData)
    }
},
watch: {
    modifyData(nval) {
        // nothing to do yet
    }
},
created() {
    console.log(2)
},
  ...
```

---

update:
'this.modifyData' was from axios.get(...) , so it would be undefined at the beginning, Though i have solved this problem but still confused why result 2 was go before result 1?

Comment: Can you link to these _articles_? Computed properties only execute during rendering and only when required by changes to reactive data

Comment: I suggest you read this ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the vue instance is initialize, the `created` function is ran.  That is why you see `2`.  The reason that the value from your computed property logs out `1` later is that computed properties are lazy, meaning that their values are not created until they are needed.